# const leading to "formal parameter different from declaration" warning

Tags: c, constants, declaration

I have seen multiple questions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18524336/2175231), for example) on this subject, but none explain the precise behavior I am seeing.

I have two functions, each declared and defined as such:

```
void PntCreate(Handle *cv);
void PntCreate(Handle * const cv)
{
    //...
}

ErrorCodes wim2Read(const char *fileName, cdCanvas *cv,
                    int onViewport);
ErrorCodes wim2Read(const char * const fileName, cdCanvas * const cv,
                   const int onViewport)
{
    //...
}
```

The declarations and definitions change only the `const` qualifiers. From the question linked above, I understand that can lead to warnings since they don't match perfectly. However, what I find curious is that the warning only appear for `PntCreate`, but not for `wim2Read`.

What is happening here? I thought it might be because the argument of `PntCreate` is a struct, but so is the second argument of `wim2Read`...

Comment: Are Canvas and cdCanvas same?

Comment: Oh hell, that was a typo! The question has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that *cv* in the definition of *wim2Read* is a pointer to *Canvas* instead of a pointer to *cdCanvas*. The `const` in both *PntCreate* and *wim2Read* has no effect on the contract between the caller and the implementation since parameters are passed by value.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question. It's been updated.

Comment: Also, note that the warning was being thrown at `PntCreate`, not `wim2Read` which had the typo.

Comment: @Wasabi Which compiler do you use? Try to create a minimal compilable example that illustrates your problem. This also lessens the risk of typing errors.